# js. table getting only first index value

Tags: javascript

```js
var columns = ['orange']
//compassvalues=compassvalues.split("~"):this is how I am getting values in array
 compassvalues=["test", "testing","ok", "or"]
var table = document.getElementById('dbtable');

for (var i = 0; i < (compassvalues.length); i++)
{
    var row = table.insertRow(-1); 
    for( var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++ ){
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1); 
        cell.className = columns[j]; //
        cell.innerHTML = compassvalues[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="dbtable" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Event</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Guys, How do i assign array values to different column. I am getting array values from db. Currently all the values are showing up in one column only.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you think `compassvalues` is that you're trying to access it with `[][]`?

Comment: What is the condition(s) for which a compassvalue item gets added to event vs name?

Comment: compassvalues[i]=values that will be under event and compassvalues[i+1] will be values under name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: updated your for loop so that *compassvalues[i]=values that will be under event and compassvalues[i+1] will be values under name.*

```js
var columns = ['orange']
//compassvalues=compassvalues.split("~"):this is how I am getting values in array
compassvalues = ["test", "testing", "ok", "or"];

var table = document.getElementById('dbtable');

//loop through the array every 2 positions
for (var i = 0; i < (compassvalues.length); i = i + 2) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);

  cell1.innerHTML = compassvalues[i];
  
  //add the 2nd column, or an empty string if we have
  //an odd number in the array
  cell2.innerHTML = compassvalues[i + 1] || '';
}
```

```html
<table id="dbtable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thx adam its working perfect. small question if you dont mind. compassvalues is an array "compassvalues = compassvalues.split("~")". i wanted to fill the table dynamically right now i am getting all the values form db in that array. is it possible to assign values to different column(right now all the values appear in event column only)

Comment: @ben yes it is possible to assign values to different columns. Recommend you update or create new question with the data and condition for assigining value to different column(s).

Comment: Thx Adam. I have updated my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Adam I have no words to describe(was trying to figure out this for a week now): Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `compassvalues` as a multidimensional array in your inner loop, even though it isnt instanced as one:

`compassvalues=["test", "testing","ok", "or"] //4 elements, one dimension`

`cell.innerHTML = compassvalues[i][j];`

In your loop, this has the effect of pulling out the first character of each string element in the `compassvalues` array. As it stands you're basically iterating over the characters in each string and creating a new cell for each one instead of a cell for each word. If you add more elements to the `columns` array you can observe this.

Replace it with

`cell.innerHTML = compassvalues[i]`

to get just the element itself.